# Problems running Rake rspec task with ci_reporter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake

I am trying to configure rake to generate reports from rspec using ci_reporter for Hudson.

Using the rake file below, the same test that passes when run with the spec command fails running with the new rake file.  First there are many warnings (which I omitted because there are too many of them to display).

It appears the ci_reporter is generating reports but they are empty.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Thanks!
-Laura

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.
require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'
require 'rake/packagetask'
require 'spec/version'
require 'spec/rake/spectask'
require 'rcov'
require 'tasks/rails'
gem 'ci_reporter'
require 'ci/reporter/rake/rspec'

def rspec_report_path
    "reports/rspec/"
end

namespace :ci do
    task :pre_ci do
        ENV["CI_REPORTS"] = rspec_report_path
        gem 'ci_reporter'
    require 'ci/reporter/rake/rspec'
end

  task :rspec => [:pre_ci, "ci:setup:rspec"]
  desc "do rspec tests and test coverage"

  @suite = Spec::Rake::SpecTask.new('rspec') do |t|
      # t.spec_files = FileList['spec/**/*_spec.rb']
      t.spec_files = FileList['spec/models/assignment_spec.rb']
      t.warning = true
      t.rcov = false
      t.rcov_dir = 'coverage'
      t.fail_on_error = false
      t.rcov_opts = ['--exclude', "kernel,load-diff-lcs\.rb,instance_exec\.rb,lib/spec.rb,lib/spec/runner.rb,^spec/*,bin/spec,examples,/gems,/Library/Ruby,\.autotest,#{ENV['GEM_HOME']}", '-I', 'lib/']
    end
end
```

Error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:52:in `method_missing': undefined method `metadata' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/rspec.rb:46:in `name'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/test_suite.rb:146
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/test_suite.rb:140:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/test_suite.rb:140
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-2.1.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:134:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-2.1.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:134:in `_nested_structures'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-2.1.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:58:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/test_suite.rb:136:in `to_xml'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/test_suite.rb:86
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/test_suite.rb:85:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/test_suite.rb:85
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-2.1.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:134:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-2.1.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:134:in `_nested_structures'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-2.1.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:58:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/test_suite.rb:84:in `to_xml'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/report_manager.rb:18:in `write_report'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/report_manager.rb:17:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/report_manager.rb:17:in `write_report'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/rspec.rb:203:in `write_report'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/rspec.rb:207:in `new_suite'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/rspec.rb:114:in `example_group_started'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/reporter.rb:19:in `example_group_started'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/reporter.rb:18:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/reporter.rb:18:in `example_group_started'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/example/example_group_methods.rb:115:in `notify'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/example/example_group_methods.rb:96:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:23:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:22:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/options.rb:153:in `run_examples'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner.rb:61:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner.rb:45
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:52:in `method_missing': undefined method `metadata' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/rspec.rb:46:in `name'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/test_suite.rb:146
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/test_suite.rb:140:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/test_suite.rb:140
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-2.1.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:134:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-2.1.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:134:in `_nested_structures'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-2.1.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:58:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/test_suite.rb:136:in `to_xml'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/test_suite.rb:86
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/test_suite.rb:85:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/test_suite.rb:85
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-2.1.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:134:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-2.1.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:134:in `_nested_structures'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-2.1.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:58:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/test_suite.rb:84:in `to_xml'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/report_manager.rb:18:in `write_report'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/report_manager.rb:17:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/report_manager.rb:17:in `write_report'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/rspec.rb:203:in `write_report'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/rspec.rb:207:in `new_suite'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ci_reporter-1.7.0/lib/ci/reporter/rspec.rb:114:in `example_group_started'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/reporter.rb:19:in `example_group_started'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/reporter.rb:18:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/reporter.rb:18:in `example_group_started'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/example/example_group_methods.rb:115:in `notify'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/example/example_group_methods.rb:96:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:23:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:22:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/options.rb:153:in `run_examples'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/command_line.rb:9:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.2/bin/spec:5
    from /usr/bin/rcov:508:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/rcov:508 
Recording test results
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception was a bug in ci_reporter that was fixed on 21 Feb 2012 (see https://github.com/nicksieger/ci_reporter/commit/48d7389f19bace8e7765d889bcd4425e3aab699b) but that fix is not part of any released version as of 26 April 2012.  The solution until it gets released is to get the gem from github.  If you're using bundler, change your Gemfile entry to:

```
gem 'ci_reporter', :git => 'git://github.com/nicksieger/ci_reporter.git'
```

Comment: Can you explain why this fixes the issue? I can see from the error that the object upon which `metadata` is called is nil, but why? It seems from the code in that file that the object `@exception` should be within scope, so why doesn't it get set to something non-nil?

Comment: Oh, nevermind I see it now. I was reading `@example` as `@exception` - bad reading on my part.